# Text mining with Python and pandas

Tags: python, pandas, text-mining

this maybe is a duplicate, but I had no luck finding it...

I am working on some text mining in Python with Pandas. I have words in a DataFrame and the Porter stemming next to it with some other statistics. This means similar words having exact same Porter stem can be found in this DataFrame. I would like to aggregate these similar words in a new column then drop the duplicates regarding Porter stem.

```
import pandas as pd
pda = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'Word': ['bank', 'hold', 'banking', 'holding', 'bank'], 'Porter': ['bank', 'hold', 'bank', 'hold', 'bank'], 'SomeData': ['12', '13', '12', '13', '12']})

pdm = pd.DataFrame(pda.groupby(['Porter'])['Word'].apply(list))
```

What I would love to have:

```
# Word      Porter               Merged    SomeData
# bank        bank      [bank, banking]          12
# hold        hold      [hold, holding]          13
# banking     bank      [bank, banking]          12
# holding     hold      [hold, holding]          13
# bank        bank      [bank, banking]          12
```

After removing duplicates:

```
# Word      Porter               Merged    SomeData
# bank        bank      [bank, banking]          12
# hold        hold      [hold, holding]          13
```

I tried to use, but I came no closer to my goals.

```
pda.join(pdm, on="Porter", how="left")``
```

Thank you for any help in advance.

EDIT: code above revised

Comment: Your example doesn't work. `pda` has no column `Porter` or `Word`, so we can't create `pdm`

Comment: Please correct the code: {'Word': ['bank', 'hold', 'banking', 'holding', 'bank'], 'Porter': ['bank', 'hold', 'bank', 'hold', 'bank'], 'SomeData': ['12', '13', '12', '13', '12']}

Answer (score 0):

You can apply a set to this instead of a list, so you are removing all the duplicates automaticly:

```
import pandas as pd
pda = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'Word': ['bank', 'hold', 'banking', 'holding', 'bank'], 
                              'Porter': ['bank', 'hold', 'bank', 'hold', 'bank'], 
                              'SomeData': ['12', '13', '12', '13', '12']})

pdm = pd.DataFrame(pda.groupby(['Porter'])['Word'].apply(set))
```

Comment: Not bad, but I am loosing my extra columns, like SomeData.

Comment: How you want to keep some data. As a list?