# How can I analyse a text from a pandas column?

Tags: python, pandas, text, text-mining

I'm used to make some analysis from text files in Python. I usually do something like:

```
f = open('filename.txt','r')
text = ""
while 1:
    line = f.readline()
    if not line:break
    text += line

f.close()

# tokenize
tokenized_word=word_tokenize(text)
.
.
.
```

However, now I'm not working with a text file, but with a Pandas dataframe. How can I get the 'text' object from a Pandas column?

I tried taking a look at the post
[Text mining with Python and pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53489987/text-mining-with-python-and-pandas), but it's not exactly what I'm looking for.

Comment: can you explain a little bit more?  do you want the text from a column ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's imagine this is your datafame:

```
import pandas as pd 
df = pd.DataFrame({ "Text": ['bla bla bla', 'Hello', 'Other sentence', 'Lets see']})
```

You can get the synonym to your code by using the `agg` function:

```
text = df['Text'].agg(lambda x: ' '.join(x.dropna())) 
text
```

Result:

```
'bla bla bla Hello Other sentence Lets see'
```

Then you can tokenize:

```
tokenized_word=word_tokenize(text)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate through the rows:

```
for idx, row in df.iterrows():
 tokenized_word=word_tokenize(row['text'])
```